# Architecture for site with clients with different needs

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure this post won't break some rules of this site, I simply don't even know how to search for such a question (I did try).

I've created a site for my company (PHP/MySQL) that produces business cards for a client of ours. They get a little form, choose a few variables and order the card, a pdf gets generated and our company prints the cards (it's printing company). We're now looking to add a second client to the site, and I have to make the site able to handle both clients but not make them aware of each other. This is all fine, and eventually we'll have lots of clients from lots of companies using the site and I plan to make it so that anyone from within the company can set up a client and their business card metrics. It's nowhere near that right now, the first client's card metrics are hardcoded in a php file, but it will eventually be somehow generating the card from layout rules pulled from the database.

Different companies have wildly different things on their business cards, different types of phone numbers, titles, qualifications, layout rules etc. I had three possible ideas of how to accomplish this on the SQL side.

1) (this is the first way and frankly I think it's awful) Make one table that has every possible kind of field and different clients use different fields. The problem with this is it will always require a programmer, my aim is to make the site (eventually) totally self sufficient. A CMS I suppose.

2) Use one table, but the columns don't have set names, just generic names (colA, colB or whatever) that are then assigned a value by another table. This would be complicated and hard to figure out structure once the app was left to do it's thing, but the idea is that it manages itself (though when something goes wrong I suppose it would be a nightmare to untangle).

3) sort of a Hybrid. The site creates a table for each client if someone creates a client, and another table just keeps track of who all the clients are. I think this could get messy.

4)some other way *shrug*

5) (Edit) Was just thinking about some way or storing key/value pairs in a table...

I'm not an experienced or trained developer, so I'm learning as I'm going (enjoying it obviously, I chose to do this for the company). I'm just looking for some direction, what path to go down. My ultimate goal is a site that doesn't require staff here to come to me to add change things about a card or details specific to to a client (like pricing, qtys they can order, their card template or whatever). Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your third choice is your most ideal option but it should be modified slightly. 
You might not be doing it this way now but you would want to think in terms of objects. From your description, I see at least two: `Client` and `Card`. You wouldn't want to create a table for each client because that will get redundant and I'm sure if you are creating a site for business cards there can't be too many fields that differ between clients.

For example set up a `Client` table like so:

```
Create table `Clients` {
`clientId` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` `text`,
... more fields
}
```

Do the same thing to set up your card table, obviously with the required fields and create corresposnding classes in `php`. I know you said that each company has wildly different things on their cards so maybe you can break it up into sections.

And eventually yes, from the sound of it you might want to look into using a CMS to manage your content, although from the sound of it, it may not be necessary. You should look into a simple MVC framework such as codeigniter or yii (Both are php frameworks). Look at a tutorial on object-oriented programming [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/) if you are just beginning.

You wouldn't want to implement your first choice because that will be a headache to fix later down the road and it's not good practice.

The second choice would also be a bad idea because it could get confusing later on and again, it isn't good practice.

Hopefully I didn't confuse you and pointed you in the right direction. Sorry, I feel like I am throwing a lot at you at once. Check out object oriented programming techniques and look at lightweight MVC frameworks for the php side.

Comment: No that's cool, thank you. I've rebuilt the site a couple of times already, it's more object oriented than it was and I tried to implement a MVC pattern, though because I was also studying at the time and didn't ave much time I kind of just did without much research. It wound up being more of a MV or CV or (MC)V pattern... ie I never really worked out the different roles of Model and Controller! The link looks interesting, I never really feel like I've learnt something properly before moving on to the next thing.